# Express returning 404 on some Firebase Auth UID's

Tags: express, rest, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Im making an api with express and firebase functions for my angular frontend. I have a route in my API to query a user document, and it throws a 404 on some of the user ID's that I send in the params.

```
this.app.get(
      "/users/:userId",
      isDocumentOwner,
      async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        debug("[GET]", "/users/:userId", "called!", "PARAM:", req.params.userId);
        try {
          if (!req.params.userId) throw "Bad request";
          const user = await Users.getUser(req.params.userId);
          res.status(200).send({
            data: user,
          });
        } catch (error) {
          res.status(400).send();
        }
      }
    );
```

This is the route im talking about.

It's really weird. I tried the same url with different user ID's, and than I got even more confused.

F2GnvvehCDUSrgXf9Y9Vq8dmGCZ2 <- Returns 404

Sz07fwEPxnRDyFG7EMQGq8kfgck2 <- Returns 200 with the user document

xCqUNpF7rvO9xvaMHjw4PYzO4473 <- Returns 200 with the user document

If anyone has experience with this particular bug please help me out, my brain is breaking rn.

SIDENOTE:
I don't throw a 404 anywhere in my code manually.
Also the param is being received by express as you see in the image

[As you see the param can be accessed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1RhE.png)

[The documents in cloud firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjC9k.png)

[The users in firebase auth (ids are being cut off but i checked them, they match)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpl4W.png)

Comment: Hi. The best way to debug this is to use the Firestore console. Go under the `logs` tab, and see what’s happening to that specific request. Maybe a permission bug? Post more details so we can help more. :)

Comment: The debug log is returning exactly what I expect. It can access the right userId param, and sidenote: I don't throw a 404 anywhere in the code.

Comment: 404 basically means it can’t find the route. Aren’t you accidentally calling the wrong route or HTTPS method with that ID?

Comment: Nope, I'm really just doing the same request just with a different id.

Comment: I also tried deleting a few accounts, and than checking if it works with the newly generated UID's, and than it actually does work. It seems to fail on only some specific UIDs. Maybe it has to do with the casing?

Comment: Ok the only thing that remains, is that the user with that ID doesn’t actually exist in your DB. Maybe a typo? Maybe you’re querying the wrong environment?

Comment: Maybe. Really weird. But I still suspect a typo or something. Anyway, glad it’s fixed.

Comment: It's not fixed. I still don't have a proper solution. I added 2 images. It all matches.

Comment: I have no idea then. I upvoted your question. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help man, appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. I hoped I could help more.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. After debugging the whole process line by line I stumbled upon an error. I forgot to return once when sending the response which caused a "ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT".